# Swift: Picker throws error when its view controller is presented programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

When I present a view controller which has a picker in it through the method `present(viewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`, the error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is thrown. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x848b34, 0x000000010eb3bc50 libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 96, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
frame #0: 0x000000010eb3bc50 libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never + 96
* frame #1: 0x000000010c19c231 Exercise Generator`createNew.viewDidLoad(self=0x00007f9d12d69b30) -> () + 177 at createNew.swift:43
frame #2: 0x000000010c19c722 Exercise Generator`@objc createNew.viewDidLoad() -> () + 34 at createNew.swift:0
frame #3: 0x000000010d32ea3d UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
frame #4: 0x000000010d32ee70 UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 27
frame #5: 0x000000010dbef6a4 UIKit`-[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
frame #6: 0x000000010d309702 UIKit`-[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 141
frame #7: 0x000000010d341e97 UIKit`-[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3956
frame #8: 0x000000010d34526b UIKit`-[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530
frame #9: 0x000000010d344d51 UIKit`-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
frame #10: 0x000000010c1b18fa Exercise Generator`openRecent.myaction(sender=0x00007f9d12c45f50, self=0x00007f9d12c451e0) -> () + 1706 at openRecent.swift:57
frame #11: 0x000000010c1b1afa Exercise Generator`@objc openRecent.myaction(sender : UIButton!) -> () + 58 at openRecent.swift:0
frame #12: 0x000000010d18e8bc UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
frame #13: 0x000000010d314c38 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
frame #14: 0x000000010d314f51 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
frame #15: 0x000000010d313e4d UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
frame #16: 0x000000010d6be304 UIKit`_UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 5645
frame #17: 0x000000010d6b8fcb UIKit`_UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1472
frame #18: 0x000000010d6b89c3 UIKit`-[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 521
frame #19: 0x000000010d6b7ba6 UIKit`-[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 286
frame #20: 0x000000010d1fdc1d UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3989
frame #21: 0x000000010d1aa9ab UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
frame #22: 0x000000010d99772d UIKit`__dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
frame #23: 0x000000010d990463 UIKit`__handleEventQueue + 4879
frame #24: 0x000000010cd0d761 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
frame #25: 0x000000010ccf298c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
frame #26: 0x000000010ccf1e76 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 918
frame #27: 0x000000010ccf1884 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
frame #28: 0x00000001113f1a6f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
frame #29: 0x000000010d18cc68 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
frame #30: 0x000000010c1af2ef Exercise Generator`main + 111 at AppDelegate.swift:12
frame #31: 0x000000011046768d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Relevant Code:
Present method:

```
func myaction(sender: UIButton!) { //several buttons are created programmatically, all trigger this function

    print("button pressed")
    print(sender.currentTitleColor)
    switch sender.tag {

    case 0 :
        print("First Button")

    case 1 :
        print("Second Button")

    default:
        print("button action from undefined button")
    }
    present(createNew(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Destination (`createNew()`)

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!{
    didSet {
       nameField.delegate = self
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var tagButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var PatientPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var OrientationPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet var tagLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!

var patientPickerData    : [String] = [String]()
var orientationPickerData: [String] = [String]()
var exerciseName: String = "Untitled"
var orientation : String = String()
var tag: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Picker info
    self.PatientPicker.dataSource = self     //Error happens here
    self.PatientPicker.delegate = self
    self.OrientationPicker.dataSource = self
    self.OrientationPicker.delegate = self
    patientPickerData = ["--Select Patient--", "No Patient"]
    orientationPickerData = ["--Select Orientation--","Standing","Reclining"]
    //End of viewDidLoad()
}
```

This should be all the code relevant to the problem. If needed, there is some more stuff I could post, but as I said earlier this works with storyboard segues and for some reason does not work when presented programmatically.

Comment: You need give more details, crash logs? some code etc, is difficult help you only guessing what is happening

Comment: Provided a backtrace

Comment: The viewContoller() is the problem

Comment: How so? I'm not quite sure precisely what is the cause.

Comment: Can you send the code snippet before trying to present the view controller

Comment: @ColePetersen are you using storyboard?

Comment: Most of the time, this is a result of forced unwrapping using !. Post the code if you want someone to help you. We aren't psychic.

Comment: As per the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) docs, please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Use a perfomsegue instead of a present...it should sort your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this works with storyboard segues

Yes, because when you do a segue you are using the view controller in the storyboard, where it has a view, and that view contains a picker view and all the outlets get hooked up.

But your `createNew` creates a different view controller, one with an empty view containing no picker view or anything else. So your outlets are never hooked up, they are nil, and you crash.

You need to do what the segue does: pull out the view controller *from the storyboard*.